# Pronunciation of "sufficient"

Tags: pronunciation

Recently, while watching Walking Dead, I heard "sufficient" pronounced differently from what I have learned twice. I learned it with a "sh" but they pronounced it like the original "suffice". Checking multiple online dictionaries indicate the way I've learned it is correct. Where does the different pronunciation come from? Is it a dialect?

**EDIT**

After trying to find the part again I can't say for sure anymore that it was Walking Dead (see comments). But I definitely heard it twice in something I watched recently and as far as I remember I only watched US productions.

Comment: Which character in what episode and season? I'm curious. (And I might overlooked it when I watched it.) If it's the latest season, I might still have it on my PVR. :-)

Comment: @DamkerngT. I'm not a 100% sure anymore. It was definitely late season 6 or early season 7. As I said I heard it twice and I think from two different characters. One of them could have been Abraham. I'll see if I can find the exact part later.

Comment: I always thought that was either literal pronunciation or snobbish language.

Comment: I haven't seen the show, but it sounds like "suffi-see-ent" is just fancy pronunciation. Sounds like something a posh british person would say on american television so that the audience knows that they are a snob.

Also check out this site if you haven't found it already: https://forvo.com/word/sufficient/#en

 - Pronunciations from around the world

Comment: @DamkerngT. Can't seem to find it. Even found the scripts online and they don't contain the word. Might be my brain fooling me and it wasn't Walking Dead. But I'm still certain I heard it twice in something I watched recently.

Comment: @AndréStannek Thanks for the info anyway. I guess I'll watch out for it when the second half of the season is back. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Likely just an accent, American English can deviate substantially from English, see potayto and potarto.

In English, the "sh" is common, I pronounce it suff-ish-ent

Answer (score 1):

I pronounce it as "suffi-shi-ent"; 
'shi' as in *ship*.